# How to remove selected files listed in the the second column of Listview?

Tags: vb.net, file

I have a listview with listed some path of files in the second column

and I want to remove all selected files listed in second column
of course I want to remove Also the items.

I tried it

```
For Each i As ListViewItem In ListView1.SelectedItems
    ListView1.Items.Remove(i)
    System.IO.File.Delete(i)
Next
```

and it's removing selected items, but not removing files selected in second column..
because i got a error

> value of type System.Windows.Forms.Listviewitem cannot be converted to string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of loop variable `i` is `ListViewItem` while `File.Delete()` accepts file path of type `string`, you need to correct that. To get file paths from second column use `ListViewItem's` `SubItems` property:

```
Dim idx As Integer = ListView1.SelectedItems.Count - 1
For i As Integer = idx To 0 Step -1
    Dim lvi As ListViewItem = ListView1.SelectedItems(i)
    System.IO.File.Delete(lvi.SubItems(1).Text)
    ListView1.Items.Remove(lvi)
Next
```

Comment: ArgumentOutOFRangeException was unhandled
| InvalidArgument=Value of 1 is not valid for index
| parameter name: index

Comment: Make sure _ListView1_ contains at least 2 columns ? At which line this exception comes ?

Comment: Line: System.IO.File.Delete(lvi.SubItems(1).ToString())

Comment: Check what are the values of these 2 ? 1. _Dim cnt As Integer = lvi.SubItems.Count_ 2. _Dim si As String = lvi.SubItems(0).ToString()_

Comment: I forgot to add a item. It's now another error || NotSupportedException was unhandled.The given path's format is not suported

Comment: What value you get for _lvi.SubItems(1).Text_ ?

Comment: I checked it now, and I get the content of the first column.

Comment: _SubItems(1)_ gives 2nd column value, if you get 1st column value then probably you are not setting 2nd column value correctly.

Answer (score 1):

- To get a value from `listviewItem`, you need to access `ListviewItem.Subitems` property. The value you want is in second column, so it is `subitems(1)`
- you can't loop into selected items and remove items in the loop like this. The selected items collection will change and you will get an exception.
- I recommand you to delete the file in a Try Catch block. If you have an exception, don't remove ListviewItem.

---

This should work.

```
If ListView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0
   For i As Integer = ListView1.SelectedItems.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
      Dim lvi As listviewItem = ListView1.SelectedItems(0)
      Try
         Dim filepath as String = lvi.subitems(1).Text
      If System.IO.File.Exists(filepath) Then
             System.IO.File.Delete(filepath)
             ListView1.Items.Remove(lvi)
          End If
      Catch ex as Exception
         ' Do something

         'you will have another exception for the next item because
         'It will try to delete the same (selectedItem(0))
         'So exit
          Exit for 
      End Try
    Next
 End If
```

Comment: not working, error in this line: System.IO.File.Delete(lvi.subitem(1)
|subitem is not a member of System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem and ')' expected
|
I added a ")" and then only 'subitem is not a member of System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem'

Comment: @28121327 You are correct, there were wrong parts in my sample code. Does the updated answer help?